# How to dynamically get values from multiple check-boxes (jquery) and copy it to textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an checkbox "Cut image" which will on select expand four more check-boxes (up, left, right, down) where you can select where image will be cut.

By default, these expanded check-boxes are selected.

What I want to achieve is:

1. If "cut image" checkbox is selected (and by default all other expanded check-boxes) append text value "Cut image: up, left, right, down" to textarea
2. If one of the expanded check-boxes are not selected (lets say "up"), remove it's value from appended text in textarea, and show only selected ones, "Cut image: left, right, down"

**Html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cut-image">
<label for="">Cut image</label>


<div id="main-group">

  <input type="checkbox" class="cut-image-up" checked>
  <label for="">up</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="cut-image-left" checked>
  <label for="">left</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="cut-image-right" checked>
  <label for="">right</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="cut-image-down" checked>
  <label for="">down</label>

</div>


<textarea name="" id="checkbox-values" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){

 $('#cut-image').on('change', function(){
   $('#main-group').toggle();

   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $('#checkbox-values').val('Cut image (up, left, right, down)');
   }else{
     $('#checkbox-values').val('');
   }

  });
})
```

Here is an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drmrsan/rf2hcmzw/7/) also.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Both of the bottom answers are valid based upon your question, and yet, they are completely different in behavior.

This is the problem product owners dont describe the behavior they want explicitly in the software world.

Example: what happens if a user clicks the main checkbox, unchecks up and left, and then unchecks the main checkbox. What should display in the textarea?  Based upon your question, it is unknown and thus, both of the answers below, are valid, yet completely different in behavior.

Comment: @simon, i agree with your comment regarding lack of details. Final behavior of application is still not clear enough because there are few more parameters i would need to include here. Now I've got a good starting point for resolving it.. Both of answers are valid as you said, and i appreciate their help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are always about a billion ways to do things like this. It seems to me like you need a couple of things:

- A way to associate each checkbox with its direction
- Something that listens for changes in the checkboxes -- as they are checked and unchecked
- Every time a checkbox is changed, we grab all the checked checkboxes, and reattach the directions to the textbox

Here's an updated version. Note the slightly different HTML...

```js
$(function() {

  $('#cut-image').on('change', function() {
    $('#main-group').toggle();

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      setCheckboxValues();
    } else {
      $('#checkbox-values').val('');
    }
    
    $('.cut-image').on('change', function() {
     setCheckboxValues()
    })

  });

})

function setCheckboxValues() {
  const allCheckedText = $('input.cut-image:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get()
  $('#checkbox-values').val(`Cut image (${allCheckedText.join(', ')})`);
}
```

```css
#cut-image,
#main-group,
#checkbox-values {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#main-group {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cut-image">
<label for="">Cut image</label>


<div id="main-group">

  <input type="checkbox" class="cut-image" checked value="up">
  <label for="">up</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="cut-image" checked value="left">
  <label for="">left</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="cut-image" checked value="right">
  <label for="">right</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="cut-image" checked value="down">
  <label for="">down</label>

</div>


<textarea name="" id="checkbox-values" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: I was close to yours, but manipulating the hider button and redoing mine was still autoloading all options, even if they weren't still checked after reshowing.  https://jsfiddle.net/rf2hcmzw/12/   Cheers for your answer

Answer (score 1):

This won't completely take care of all the various scenarios but will give you a good start point

Add values to the checkboxes and build array of those values using jQuery map(). Then `join()` those array values to add to the text

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cut-image-up" value="up" checked>
```

JS

```
$('#cut-image').on('change', function() {
  $('#main-group').toggle();

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

    // array of checked checkbox values
    var directions = $('#main-group :checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value
    }).get().join(', ');

    $('#checkbox-values').val('Cut image (' + directions + ')');
  } else {
    $('#checkbox-values').val('');
  }

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rf2hcmzw/10/)**</kbd>

Comment: Amazing how your answer is completely different in behavior to JSilvs, yet they both fulfill the OP's question because of lack of detail.  I upped your vote, although my solution was closer to JSilvs

Comment: @charlietfl - sorry for my late response, and thanks for your answer. I'll review it, and see which of the answers suit my needs.